# Bouncing animation while changing view frame

Tags: ios

Add bouncing animation while changing UIVIew frame. I only know how to change frame but I don't know how to set bouncing effect while changing view frame. Below is my code....

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{

CGRect frame = viewContent.frame;
frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(viewContentFullDetail);
viewContent.frame = frame;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {        }];
```

You can check animated gif image on below link. I want to add animation not same like this but near to this. Main animation are unfolding and bouncing effect.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9k_Shyb5v62eFdxWXhYeXV3a0E

Please help. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to try this

```
int duration, damping, velocity;
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 
    usingSpringWithDamping:damping initialSpringVelocity:velocity 
    options:0 animations:^{
    // your animation code here

} completion:nil];
```

Play with the damping and velocity values to know more about this feature in the animation code.
[here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2217000) is the link for a tutorial

Comment: Thanks bro... This is very helpful for me. I implemented in my app.  And can you please guide for fold and unfold animation effect?

Comment: that would be 2 sets of animation. the fold and unfold one. 
Fold would fill in the `^animation` block and unfold animation would be inside the `^completion` block

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll implement fold and unfold latter. But I still don't understand the value of velocity. I set damping value. But what about velocity?. My view is damping but it is not like what I want.